# How to add custom php files in magento module?

Tags: php, magento

I am building a Magento extension for tax calculation and I have multiple places where I have to call a web service call. For that reason I have to create a PHP class that I want to create form where I can call web service, so I have less boilerplate code. Here are the following places I need to call the webservice from

```
\app\code\community\Company\MyModule\Model\Tax\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax.php
\app\code\community\Company\MyModule\Model\Observer.php
```

I already have created few classes and put them under `\lib\my_libname\` folder. When I try to access that file I get the following error though:
exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(WebServiceCall.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in

```
C:\wamp\www\magento1\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94' in C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\magento1\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(94): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(MyModule...', 'C:\\wamp\\www\\mag...', 94, Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\magento1\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(94): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('WebServiceCall')
#3 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\community\Company\MyModule\Model\Tax\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax.php(9): spl_autoload_call('WebServiceCall')
#4 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address.php(1013): Company_MyModule_Model_Tax_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax->collect(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address))
#5 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote.php(1331): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address->collectTotals()
#6 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Cart.php(458): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->collectTotals()
#7 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php(223): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->save()
#8 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->addAction()
#9 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('add')
#10 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 C:\wamp\www\magento1\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 C:\wamp\www\magento1\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being to obvious, but its telling you that the file is not there. Its been a while since i did PHP, but (as the stack trace is also hinting at), you might wanna look into how you autoloading is set up.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to understand how Magento loads files:

```
    /**
 * Set include path
 */
$paths = array();
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';

$appPath = implode(PS, $paths);
set_include_path($appPath . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));
```

Second thing is the folder & class name location - Magento is using autoloader so you just call the class like:

```
$object = new My_Class();
```

This would translate to a call to:

```
lib/My/Class.php
```

If you are on *NIX systems, then this is all case-sensitive.

If you check the autoloader you will see:

```
$classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
$classFile.= '.php';
return include $classFile;
```

So in your case, the path should be: lib/My/Libname/ClassName.php

Comment: mine is structured like this \lib\Libname\src\SomeClass.php and \lib\Libname\src\ws\someclass.php